# web2py make 20 entries on a page

Tags: html-table, web2py

I have a lot of entries in the table that I want to display, and as I already have other things on the same page, I want to make this table show only 10-20 entries per page. How can I add that?

Here is the code I wrote in view:

```
{{if prints:}}
<h3>{{=T('Print history:')}}</h3>
{{i=0}}
<table>
    <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>{{=T('Component name')}}</th>
            <th>{{=T('Component code')}}</th>
            <th>{{=T('Number of components')}}</th>
            <th>{{=T('Printing date')}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{for design in prints:}}
            <tr><td>{{=i+1}}</td><td>
         {{=design.fk_printhistory_componentcatalog.component_name}}</td><td>
         {{=design.fk_printhistory_componentcatalog.component_code}}</td><td>
         {{=design.no_of_components}}</td><td>{{=design.time_stamp}}</td></tr>
        {{i=i+1}}
        {{pass}}
    </tbody>
</table>
{{pass}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming, you are getting `prints` from db and wants pagination in your table.

You can use `limitby` in `select`. [This web2py slice will help you.](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1623/pagination-with-limitby)

Comment: That's kind of useful, but i want to be able to see all the results. This way i am seeing just 10 entries, and I can't click on anything to see more of them

Comment: create a pagination panel below the table like previous, next. Use a vars like page, which store the value of the page you are in. if you want to see next 10 tables then your url would be `hostname/APP/CONTROLLER/FUNCTION?page=2`.

Comment: This functionality is already implemented in the slice. `<a href={{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)-1})}}>Previous</a>` |
`<a href={{=URL(vars={'page':int(request.vars.page)+1})}}>Next</a>`

Comment: The official documentation also includes a pagination recipe: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14/other-recipes#Pagination

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write any manual [pagination](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14/other-recipes#Pagination) code, you might also consider using [SQLFORM.grid](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-grid) (which has built in pagination). You could use a join query in order to get the `component_name` and `component_code` values from the referenced table.

Even if you stick with the manual method, you might be better off using a join to get the `component_name` and `component_code` fields, as the recursive selects in your current code are resulting in two additional database selects for every row.